# PLSQL BETWEEN procedure not working

Tags: sql, plsql

I am very new to PL/SQL and I recently created a new procedure which seems to compile properly but when I exec the procedure it does not display anything.

What i am trying to accomplish is to select the zip code with the maximum # of houses affected between the two inputs into the procedure which are outage_start_time timestamp, outage_end_time timestamp.

Table:
OUTAGE_ID,  OUTAGE_START,OUTAGE_END,OUTAGE_ZIPCODE, OUTAGE_STATUS,  HOUSES_AFFECTED

Procedure:

```
create or replace procedure start(outage_start_time timestamp, outage_end_time timestamp)
as
  Cursor test is 
  select outage_zipcode 
  from outage 
  where HOUSES_AFFECTED in (select max(HOUSES_AFFECTED)from outage)
  and outage_start_time between outage_start and outage_end 
  and outage_end_time  between outage_start and outage_end;
 average varchar(256);
BEGIN
  Open test;
  Loop
    fetch test into average;
    exit when test%notfound;
    dbms_output.put_line(average);
 end loop;
end;
```

Comment: The procedure you wrote here is incomplete. Please provide the full text.

Comment: updated with entire procedure

Comment: Are you running from sqlplus and did you `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` before running? (i.e. try writing a procedure that just writes out "hello world" and make sure that is working for you; then make sure your query actually returns results, ...)

Comment: yes I am and yes i did. It just says "PL/SQL procedure successfully completed."

Comment: are you sure : the cursor query is returning some data?    from outage 
  where HOUSES_AFFECTED in (select max(HOUSES_AFFECTED)from outage)
  and outage_start_time between outage_start and outage_end 
  and outage_end_time  between outage_start and outage_end;               Run this select statement. I dont think the table has the data which satisfies the given condition predicates.

Comment: What you truly want isn't clear  imho. Do you just want a single zipcode as the output?, or all zipcodes affected by an outage? perhaps you want just the unique list of zipcodes? why not concentrate on getting a simple select query to work first, then produce the stored proc.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible test case, and make sure the query returns rows before focusing on PL/SQL. At the moment you don't know if it's a technical PL/SQL issue or something to do with the `between` keyword as suggested in your question, or just that there isn't any data matching your criteria.

Comment: what i am trying to accomplish is to select the zip code with the maximum # of houses affected between the two inputs into the procedure which are outage_start_time timestamp, outage_end_time timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account your comments, I can suppose your `average` variable contains `NULL` value. In SQL*Plus it will look like an empty line. To make sure you can add something to output:

```
dbms_output.put_line('average value is: ' || average);
```

or even

```
dbms_output.put_line('average value is: ''' || average || '''');
```

The last one is very good when you need distinguish `NULL` value from space symbol(s).

`average` variable could be null due to your query returns no rows. Why - it is a question to your data.

Comment: i thought the exact same thing but there is something else odd about it, I have other cursors(not shown above) in the same procedure and when I add this cursor they don't output anymore. It's like this one cursor breaks it. Without the 'test' cursor they work as expected.

Comment: @user2402107 If you want any other help, you have to provide information how to reproduce this behavior. Now I can't say anything else. With this new information, it is a different question. Maybe you have `exception` sections, which hide errors? Maybe a result of a query depend on a result of previously executed one?

Comment: i guess my best question would then be, do you think the above select query is syntactically correct and should do its desired behavior based upon the logic?

Comment: You said you have other cursors. I can't say anything until I'll see them, but also I can't guarantee that I'll say anything if I'll see.

Comment: if I remove this: )and outage_start_time between outage_start and outage_end 
and outage_end_time  between outage_start and outage_end;..... it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your query does not return any rows. Run this:

```
select outage_start, outage_end
  from outage 
 where HOUSES_AFFECTED in (select max(HOUSES_AFFECTED)from outage)
```

and check if there are any records for which both outage_start_time and outage_end_time, which you pass to your procedure, fall between outage_start and outage_end. I'm pretty sure there are no such records. Remember that if  outage_start or outage_end is null then your WHERE condition is not fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

without sample data and an expected result/output it's almost impossible to know what you are really seeking.

I would develop the appropriate query first. Maybe this will help:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      outage_zipcode
FROM  (
            SELECT
                  MAX(HOUSES_AFFECTED) over(partition by 1) as MX
                , HOUSES_AFFECTED
                , outage_zipcode
            FROM outage
      AND (    %1 BETWEEN outage_start AND outage_end
            OR %2   BETWEEN outage_start AND outage_end
            )
   )
WHERE HOUSES_AFFECTED = MX
;
```

Comment: What i am trying to accomplish is to select the zip code with the maximum # of houses affected between the two inputs into the procedure which are outage_start_time timestamp, outage_end_time timestamp.

Comment: I  altered the wuery above. The point of my suggestion is for you to write a query that works and produces the right result, the produce a procedure. One issue you have in your existing query is that the max calculation inst filtered by the dates so you may only ever find a match occasionally. Work on the wuery first. Get that right. Then make it a procedure.